# echo() doesn't output anything for anonymous users

Tags: forms

I am working on my own form module for Drupal 7.

I tried to set some default text depending on a cookie was set or not. It works perfectly as long as your are logged in; once you are an anonymous user, it doesn't read/write the cookie.

I tried to debug this by putting in a few calls to `echo()`, and `drupal_set_message()`, but they are only shown when I'm logged in; they don't show for anonymous users. I can't figure out why.

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the code I am using.

```
$serviceType = "";
$serviceName = "";
if (isset($_COOKIE["kms_hoststring_name"])) {
  $serviceName = $_COOKIE["kms_hoststring_name"];
  $serviceType = $_COOKIE["kms_hoststring_type"];
}
drupal_set_message("test");
echo "TEST";
$form['serviceType'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Service Type:'),
  '#default_value' => t($serviceType),
);

$form['serviceName'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Service Name'),
  '#default_value' => t($serviceName),
);

//Deletes cookies after use.
echo "TEST1";
if (isset($_COOKIE["kms_hoststring_name"])){
  setcookie("kms_hoststring_name", "", time()-60000, "/");
  setcookie("kms_hoststring_type", "", time()-60000, "/");
  echo "TEST2".$_COOKIE["kms_hoststring_name"];
}
```

None of the `echo()` or `drupal_set_message()` calls output anything for anonymous users.
When I log in, I see the output of those function calls.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a sample of your code?  It's hard to diagnose your issue without knowing what you're actually trying to do :(

Comment: Added a code sample.

Comment: What function has the code? Probably, the whole code block is executed for authenticated user only.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal have much better tools for debugging than echo. You can sent a message to the watchdog log with the [watchdog](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7) function. And if you install the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module you get a few more funcions like [dpm()](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) to easily send messages or [dd()](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7) to write onto the drupal debug log.

Comment: The devel module also needs to set correct permissions, otherwise, `dpm()` will output nothing for anonymous users.